# Probability posterior versus likelihood

Tags: probability

I am trying to grasp the difference between the two terms in bayes theorem:

$\underbrace{p(\theta|X)}_{\text{posterior}} =\frac{\overbrace{p(\theta)}^{\text{prior}}\overbrace{p(X|\theta)}^{\text{likelihood}}}{\underbrace{p(X)}_{\text{evidence}}}=\frac{\overbrace{p(\theta)}^{\text{prior}}\overbrace{p(X|\theta)}^{\text{likelihood}}}{\underbrace{\int p(\theta)p(X|\theta)d\theta}_{\text{evidence}}}$

I am trying to understand why the posterior is considered to be a probability while the likelihood is not. The only material that helped me gain some insight [is this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhoEwC9R8pA).

It seems to be related that $\theta$ are considered to be parameters of distribution while $X$ is a variable. What is happening if instead of parameters $\theta$ the likelihood was $p(X|Y)$ where $Y$ is another variable? Isn't this entity a probability?

Comment: Probabilities sum to $1$, and probability densities integrate to $1$.  Likelihoods do not have to have this property

Comment: In case that X and Y are variables, how can you prove that? I cannot see the difference in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the likelihood function is given by $ L(x_1\ldots x_n| \theta) $: conditional to the parameter, it is a function of the $x_1\ldots x_n$. If the data is an i.i.d sample of $X$ random variable, you'll have:

$$ L(x|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i|\theta), $$ where $f(\cdot|\theta)$ is the probability density function. Note that the likelihood doesn't need to integrate $1$ (can you say why?). On the other hand:

$$ h(\theta|x_1\ldots x_n) \propto L(x|\theta)p(\theta) $$ is indeed a probability. This integrates one because of the marginal $f(\boldsymbol{x})$, which acts roughly speaking as a "propotionality constant" (it's an integral and it doesn't depend on any unknown quantity, so it's a real number). The main idea is that the posterior is an update of your original pdf for the data given the priori information in $p(\theta)$ and the observed
data $x_1\ldots x_n$.

**Edit and notes on difference between classic and bayesian approach**

You have to consider that the inferencial problem of yours is about the unknown quantity $\theta$. For the classical ML estimate, you hold the data fixed and make point estimation based on the likelihood function: assuming the data is a random sample of $X | \theta$, we write the likelihood function as a function of the parameters holding on the data fixed and maximize it with respect to $\theta$. If your random sample is $X_1\ldots X_n$ sampled from a distribution $X|\theta$ and is iid, then your maximum likelihood estimate will be:

$$ \arg \max_{\theta} L(x|\theta) = \arg \max_\theta \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i|\theta), $$ which you obtain maximizing the fucntion with respect to $\theta$, fixing the data.

For the Bayesian approach, you have again a random sample, say iid  $X_1\ldots X_n$ sampled from a distribution $X|\theta$. However, you consider the parameter $\theta$ as a random variable, with probability function $p(\theta)$, which should reflect your uncertainty on $\theta$. Then you use Bayes theorem to write:

$$ h(\theta| x_1\ldots x_n) = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i|\theta) f(\theta)}{f(x_1 \ldots x_n)}. $$

Notice that the marginal $f(x_1 \ldots x_n)$ is a real number, not a random variable (it's a function of the observed data only!!), given by $\int_\Theta \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i|\theta) p(\theta)$. This is the reason why $h(\theta|x_1 \ldots x_n)$ integrate one, because the marginal $f(x_1 \ldots x_n)$ is the integral in the whole parameter space.

Now because it's usually not straightforward to compute $f(x_1 \ldots x_n)$ and $h(\theta|x_1\ldots x_n)$ is a function of the unknown quantity $\theta$ we can write:

$$ h(\theta| x_1\ldots x_n) \propto \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i|\theta) f(\theta), $$ because since we know it will integrate one, we can calculate $f(x_1 \ldots x_n)$ after we know the kernel of the $h(\theta | x_1 \ldots x_n)$. If these are known distributions, there are pretty straightforward ways to evaluate it.

Hope I could help!

Comment: "Note that the likelihood doesn't need to integrate 1 (can you say why?)" is that the probability density function $f(x_{i}|\theta)$ should integrate to one? I am not sure why this holds. 

This integrates one because of the marginal (), which acts roughly speaking as a "proportionality constant", isn't $f(\theta)$ act in the same manner if we inverse the Bayesian theorem?

Comment: @JoseRamon $f(x|\theta)$ will integrate one, as it is the pdf of the random variable $X$. If however you have a random sample $X_1 \ldots X_n$ of size $n$, then the likelihood doesn't integrate one, because you hold the data fixed and vary the $\theta$, it's a function of the parameter. Write a toy example: the normal pdf obviously integrate one, but $\prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i|\theta)$ when $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, 1)$ does not.

Comment: @JoseRamon for your second question, I will edit my answer.

Comment: I think the more I dive into the more I am confused. In my equation I shared I can solved in respect to likelihood and then it is an entity that solely depends on probabilities. In this way of thinking I cannot see why is not a probability as well.

So, if the $\theta$ is constant then likelihood is a probability but if $\theta$ varies then it is just a function. Is that right?

Comment: @JoseRamon imagine $f(x|\theta)$ is a pdf of an exponential distribution. It's conditional to $\theta$: given $\theta$, $f(x|\theta) = \theta e^{-\theta x}, x \in \mathbb{R}_+$. So if I know $\theta$, I know the probabilities associated to $X|\theta$. Now imagine otoh that I don't know $\theta$, but I have a random sample that I drawed from $X|\theta$. The whole point is that I want to estimate $\theta$ with say $\hat{\theta}$  estimator. The inference is on $\theta$, given the observed draw of $X|\theta$.

Comment: @JoseRamon In the equation you shared, $p(\theta|X)$ is a probability density. I think the point you're missing is that $f(x|\theta)$ is a probability density, but $L(x_1\ldots x_n|\theta) = f(x_1 \ldots x_n|\theta)$ is not. Note that the likelihood function is a function of the **parameter** $\theta$ only, with the observations $x_1\ldots x_n$ held as a fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided more theoretical explanations, but I want to illustrate the issue with a specific example so that you can connect the concepts to an actual practical situation.

Suppose we have a sequence of iid Bernoulli trials, $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$, where each $X_i \in \{0,1\}$ with $\Pr[X_i = 1] = \theta$ for some unknown parameter $\theta \in [0,1]$.  We cannot observe this parameter directly--think of it like being given a coin whose probability of landing heads is $\theta$, and while you don't know what this probability is, you can infer its value based on any number of flips you choose.

So the sufficient statistic $$S_n \mid \theta = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, \theta)$$ represents the total number of heads flipped out of $n$ trials, and its PMF is $$\Pr[S_n = x \mid \theta] = \binom{n}{x} \theta^x (1-\theta)^{n-x}, \quad x \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n\}. \tag{1}$$  So far, this should be nothing new.  You choose to flip the coin $n$ times and observe the total number of heads, and a natural estimator for $\theta$ would be $\hat \theta = S_n/n$.  We can confirm that $$\sum_{x=0}^n \Pr[S_n = x \mid \theta] = 1,$$ that is to say, the PMF in $(1)$ does truly define a proper probability mass function.

But now in the Bayesian context, $\theta$ is itself a random variable, and given some observed data from your experiment, $S_n = x$, the equation $(1)$ also represents a *likelihood* function $\mathcal L(\theta \mid S_n = x)$ for the parameter $\theta$.  But notice the difference here:  whereas previously, $(1)$ as a PMF is regarded as a function whose support is on $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ and whose range is in $[0,1]$, the likelihood is a function of $\theta \in [0,1]$--that is to say, it has continuous rather than discrete support.  Moreover, as it is written, its integral over its support does **not** integrate to $1$.  You can check this explicity:

$$\int_{\theta = 0}^1 \binom{n}{x} \theta^x (1-\theta)^{n-x} \, d\theta = \binom{n}{x} \frac{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(n-x+1)}{\Gamma(n+2)} = \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!} \frac{x!(n-x)!}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{n+1}, \tag{2}$$ where we have used the restriction that $x$ must be an integer between $0$ and $n$.

So for instance, if $n = 11$ and you observed $S_{11} = 7$, then the likelihood function is $$\mathcal L(\theta \mid S_{11} = 7) = \binom{11}{7} \theta^7 (1-\theta)^4,$$ and if you plot this function, you can see that there is a choice for $\theta$ that maximizes $\mathcal L$, namely $\hat \theta = 7/11$, but $\mathcal L$ does not constitute a probability density for $\theta$.  Instead, you have to normalize this likelihood by multiplying it by $n+1$, and then it does become a density.  This is precisely what is being done in Bayes' theorem.  The denominator $p(X)$ in your notation represents the marginal or unconditional probability of $X$, which in our example is the integral $(2)$ we calculated by integrating over a uniform prior distribution for $\theta$.

Of course, we need not choose a uniform prior.  We can choose *any* prior distribution, so long as it constitutes a probability density for $\theta$ on $[0,1]$.  This is the factor $p(\theta)$ in your formula, and then the marginal formula is an application of the law of total probability.

Comment: I am trying to digest your answer. So is it the nature of variables that defining the difference between probability and likelihood?

Comment: @JoseRamon Think of it this way.  Say I have some function $f(a,b)$.  If I treat $b$ as fixed, then we are interested in the behavior of $f$ as $a$ varies.  Maybe its sum or integral over $a$ will equal to $1$, maybe not.  But now if I treat $a$ as fixed and we are interested in the behavior of $f$ as $b$ varies, there is no requirement that it must sum/integrate to $1$ over the values of $b$.  In either case, it is the same function, but the **context** is different because the variables mean different things to us.

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood is the $f(\textbf x|\theta)$ with the observed data plugged in, regarded as a function of $\theta$.

Since it is a function of $\theta$, and not the "argument" in the conditional pdf $f(\textbf X|\theta)$ -- i.e. it is a function of the random variable being conditioned on and not the argument -- it is not a pdf in terms of $\theta$ and doesn't sum or integrate to 1 with respect to $\theta$.

Nevertheless there are some shortcomings with the preceding discussion. $\theta$ does not even have to be a random variable. It can just be considered unknown. (This leads to maximum likelihood estimation.)

Any of the probabilistic statements regarding the likelihoods are correct, i.e. $f(\textbf x|\theta_1)>f(\textbf x|\theta_2)$ means the data were more likely to have been observed under the first parameter than the second. It is not a statement that $P(\theta=\theta_1|\textbf x)>P(\theta=\theta_2|\textbf x)$. This requires going through the prior and posterior analysis in your post and treating $\theta$ as a random variable.

Comment: I could not follow the first part of your answer "Since it is a function of $\theta$, and not the "argument" in the conditional pdf ". Is it possible to give bit more insights?

Comment: @Jose $f(X|\theta)$ is a pdf if $\theta$ is held constant. It will integrate/sum to 1 with respect to $X$. But it is not a pdf with respect to $\theta$ the same way that $g(X|Y)$ sums to 1 with respect to $X$ but not to $Y$ if they are two random variables. The likelihood is the conditional pdf with the data plugged in ($f(x|\theta)$) as a function of $\theta$, so not a pdf. After plugging in the observed data, the only variable becomes $\theta$, and it is not a pdf with respect to $\theta$.